# importar una función de otro archivo .ipynb en jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, packages, python-import

Tengo dos archivos en python 2.3 , trabajo en jupyer notebook. 
quiero importar las funciones de un archivo a otro.
he leído que tengo que actualizar a python 3.4 o superior lo cual no se como y posteriormente installar algun tipo de package .

alguien puede ayudarme ?

Comment: El paquete es seguramente  [ipynb](https://pypi.org/project/ipynb/) que efectivamente según su setup.py requiere Python 3.4 o superior. La [instalación de Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) va a depender del **sistema operativo** que uses, luego habría que ver si lo que quieres importar es compatible con Python 3 porque ( aparte del salto a la rama 3) Python 2.3 ya tiene sus días (2005).

Answer (score 1):

Los *notebooks* son mas una secuencia de código que un módulo del que puedas reusar sus funciones. Te aconsejo convertir el notebook en script y luego editarlo para quitar el código sobrante:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to script notebook.ipynb
```

También se puede hacer lo mismo exportando desde las opciones del menú de jupyter.